# Is there a way for me to grab the data from MySQL DB and display it in a bootstrap table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <!-- [SEARCH FORM] -->
 <form method="post" action="1-form.php">
  <h1>SEARCH</h1>
  <input type="text" name="search" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
 </form>

 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  // SEARCH FOR USERS
  require "2-search.php";
  
  // DISPLAY RESULTS
  if (count($results) > 0) {
    foreach ($results as $r) {
      printf($r['name']);
      printf($r['email']);
      printf($r['phone']);
      printf($r['industry']);
      printf($r['about']);
    }
  } else {
    echo "No results found";
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my form.php code. This is where I need the table to be. So far I've managed to grab the data from the database and display it but in a single line. Here's the backend search.php code just in case:

```
<?php
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_NAME', 'db');
  define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
  define('DB_USER', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";charset=" . DB_CHARSET . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false ]
    );
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
    }
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `service_providers` WHERE `industry` LIKE ?");
    $stmt->execute(["%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"]);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) { echo json_encode($results); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate through each result and output it with the elements using `echo` like the snippet below. you echo out the html element and concatenate it with the data from your db

you can then use bootstrap classes in the tables and tds

```
<body>
    
    <table class="">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php
          foreach ($results as $res)
          {
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td class="">'. $res['name'] .'</td>';
             echo '<td class="">'. $res['phone'] .'</td>';
             echo '<td class="">'. $res['email'] .'</td>';
             echo '<tr>';
          }

       ?>
    
    </tbody>
    
    </table>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: Hello, Thank You so much CodeCreate. A few tweaks and it worked fine!